# Create a list of dictionaries under conditional

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I got a json format data.I want to extract some useful data from it, so I need to use some loop to do it.
here is my code:

```
data=json.loads(res.text)

for item in data['leagues'][0]['events']:

    for xx in item['periods']:

        if 'moneyline' in xx.keys():

            md=xx['moneyline']

            print(md)
```

I got result like this:

> {'away': 303.0, 'home': 116.0, 'draw': 223.0}
>
> {'away': 1062.0, 'home': -369.0, 'draw': 577.0}
>
> {'away': 337.0, 'home': 109.0, 'draw': 217.0}
>
> {'away': 297.0, 'home': 110.0, 'draw': 244.0}
>
> {'away': 731.0, 'home': -240.0, 'draw': 415.0}

How can I combine this separate data into a Dictionary form?

I modify my code into:

`data=json.loads(res.text)`

`dlist=[]`

```
for item in data['leagues'][0]['events']:
     for xx in item['periods']:  
        if 'moneyline' in xx.keys():
                d=xx['moneyline']
                dlist.append(d)
                print(dlist)
```

Thanks

Comment: Don't post Python code without indentation. The indentation affects the meaning of the code.

Comment: please can you fix the code in the question

Comment: I am really Sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to use a list to store the `md` dictionaries from `xx['moneyline']`, and store the keys of this dictionary in another dictionary, where you will store all values of the `md` dictionaries. For each key, a list stores the values in the original `md` dictionary. The result would be something like this:

```
{'home': [116.0, -369.0, 109.0, 110.0, -240.0], 'away': [303.0, 1062.0, 337.0, 297.0, 731.0], 'draw': [223.0, 223.0, 223.0, 223.0, 223.0, 223.0, 223.0, 223.0, 223.0, 223.0, 223.0, 223.0, 223.0, 223.0, 223.0, 223.0, 577.0, 217.0, 244.0, 415.0]}
```

Step 1:

```
data=json.loads(res.text)
list_dictionary = []  #Initialise an empty list to store the dictionaries
for item in data['leagues'][0]['events']:
    for xx in item['periods']:
        if 'moneyline' in xx.keys():
            md=xx['moneyline']
            list_dictionary.append(md).  #Append dictionary item to the list
```

Step 2: Get the information about the keys in the `md` dictionary, and store these as the keys in an empty dictionary. Initialise an empty list for all keys in the empty dictionary.

```
dictionary={}
for key in md.keys():
    dictionary.update({key:[]})
```

Step 3: Iterate through the list_dictionary obtained in step 1, and for each `md` dictionary in this list, update `dictionary` with all the values.

```
for dict in list_dictionary:
    for key, value in dict():
        dictionary[key].append(value)
```

This is how you can get all the information in a single dictionary, where the keys correspond to a list of values.

```
data=json.loads(res.text)
list_dictionary = []  #Initialise an empty list to store the dictionaries
dictionary={}    #Initialise an empty dictionary to store all the retrieved data as `md`
for item in data['leagues'][0]['events']:
    for xx in item['periods']:
        if 'moneyline' in xx.keys():
            md=xx['moneyline']
            list_dictionary.append(md).  #Append dictionary item to the list
            for key in md.keys():
                dictionary.update({key:[]}) 

#Store all the `md` values in dictionary as list 
for dict in list_dictionary:
    for key, value in dict.iteritems():
        dictionary[key].append(value)
```

Comment: Thank you so much. but at  `for key, value in dict():`
I got "TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable"

Comment: I modify the last part of your code into:
`for key in dict.keys():
        for value in dict.values():
            dictionary[key].append(value)`
It works

Comment: Oops, I made a mistake in that line. It should have been `for key, value in dict.iteritems()`, I updated the solution. :)

Comment: It should be `dict.items()`,There is no iteritems method. Thanks.

Comment: There is a `iteritems()` function for a dictionary in Python 2. You must be using Python 3 which has this function removed.